# compare two tables against their columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables `Table1` & `Table2` both having say 10 columns

I want to compare these two tables against each of their column values and select **only those records for which there is more than three column matches**..

ie.,

`Table1.Col1` value matches with `Table2.Col1` value 
AND `Table1.Col2` value matches `Table2.Col2` value 
AND `Table1.Col3` value matches `Table2.Col3` value

OR

`Table1.Col2` value matches with `Table2.Col2` value 
AND `Table1.Col4` value matches `Table2.Col4` value 
AND `Table1.Col6` value matches `Table2.Col6` value and so on...

How to write a simple and smart query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join with an or condition and then filter based on the number of fields that are matching (I only worked up to 4 fields, add as many as you need).

```
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
  on t1.field1 = t2.field1 
  or t1.field2 = t2.field2
  or t1.field3 = t2.field3
  or t1.field4 = t2.field4
where 
   ( case when t1.field1 = t2.field1 then 1 else 0 end 
   + case when t1.field2 = t2.field2 then 1 else 0 end 
   + case when t1.field3 = t2.field3 then 1 else 0 end 
   + case when t1.field4 = t2.field4 then 1 else 0 end
   ) >= 3
```

If you're lazy like me you can generate the statement for all fields like this.

```
select 'select * ' union all
select '  from table1 t1' union all
select '  join table2 t2' union all
select '    on 1 = 1 ' union all
select '   and t1.' + t1.name + ' = t2.' + t2.name  from sys.columns t1 join sys.columns t2 on t1.name = t2.name where t1.object_id = object_id('table1') and t2.object_id = object_id('table2')
union all
select 'where ( 0' union all
select '   + case when t1.' + t1.name + ' = t2.' + t2.name + ' then 1 else 0 end ' from sys.columns t1 join sys.columns t2 on t1.name = t2.name where t1.object_id = object_id('table1') and t2.object_id = object_id('table2')
union all 
select '      ) >= 3'
```

(Run the query and copy paste the result.)

Comment: You can put the where part directly into the join part and drop the where part

Comment: I don't like to do that as it is more a "filter" than a pure join condition, but indeed, it will work the same.